# reveal.js background color choices

Tags: html, reveal.js

I've been working with [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/) a bit and you can change the background of individual slides with something referred to as the global state as seen [here](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/11) in the demo.

Are there other colors besides the ones mention (-soothe, -blackout
and -alert) on this slide that can be applied (hit down key in the presentation to see the colors)? If so what colors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this to e.g. have a different background color for the final slide:

Declare a style for the background (given the class "the-end"):

```
  html.the-end .state-background {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
  }
```

Then have the final slide look like this:

```
<section data-state='the-end'>
  <h1>__END__</h1>
  <br>
  <h3>Thank you!</h3>
</section>
```

**EDIT (added by tyler rinker)** You are correct but I wanted to be more explicit for future searchers.  I added the following two segments.

**Added this to reveal.min.css**

```
.orange .reveal .state-background{background:rgba(255,165,0,1)}
```

**Added this to reveal.css**

```
.orange .reveal .state-background {
    background: rgba( 255, 165, 0, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Where do I declare the style?

Comment: Answer my own question in an edit to your answer.  Thanks for the response.  +1 and the check.

Comment: FYI I've added a few more color options in the default styles: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/css/reveal.css#L1242

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't add any presentation specific things to the library, I'd probably just add the styles inline in the presentation itself to start with.