# reveal.js: visibility of slide number

Tags: javascript, css, reveal.js

I'm trying to get a reveal.js presentation to print slide numbers. I've used the code in http://htmlcheats.com/reveal-js/reveal-js-tutorial-reveal-js-for-beginners/ and [Changing the background-image style in Reveal.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134146/changing-the-background-image-style-in-reveal-js) with http://jsfiddle.net/dirkk0/asya4grv/ . Everything renders as expected except slide numbers.

I notice that despite having `slideNumber: true` in `Reveal.initialize()` there are no slide number visible in the  http://jsfiddle.net/dirkk0/asya4grv/ rendering. I've also tried using `Reveal.configure({ slideNumber: true });` within slide `<section>` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a full `reveal.js` CDN to test with, but from what I can tell the `sliderNumber` option does not work in the minified version (http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/2.5.0/js/reveal.min.js). I believe to use it you will need to download the full [framework](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/) (both css and reveal.js files) then put them on your web server locally.