# dim the background image in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reveal.js

I'm using reveal.js: I'd like to display a full-screen image as a background, and once I move to a different slide I'd like to blur or dim it. 
Looking at [Changing the background-image style in Reveal.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134146/changing-the-background-image-style-in-reveal-js), I've tried this in my css:

```
.html.blur .backgrounds {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
 -moz-filter: blur(10px);
 -o-filter: blur(5px);
 -ms-filter: blur(5px);
 filter: blur(5px);
}
```

and then in my markdown document I do an html comment with

```
.slide: data-background="figs/background.svg" data-background-size="contain" data-state="blur"
```

which creates a `<section>` tag with `data-state="blur"` inside. However, the background doesn't get blurred -- what am I missing?

Comment: May depends upon browsers

Comment: Can you make a fiddle code

Comment: I borrowed the fiddle from the SO question I linked to above, and modified it: http://jsfiddle.net/k85qny9k/2/ -- the second slide should be blurred

Comment: sorry, had a typo -- here's the fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/k85qny9k/4/ -- this seems to work, but it doesn't work in my actual slideshow... humm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just a typo: no "." in front of html...

This will work and in addition to the blurring, do some dimming and saturation change, which will make the foreground text easier to read:

```
html.dim .backgrounds {
   -webkit-filter: blur(4px) saturate(.5) brightness(.8);
   -moz-filter: blur(4px) saturate(.7) brightness(.9);
   -o-filter: blur(4px) saturate(.7) brightness(.9);
   -ms-filter: blur(4px) saturate(.7) brightness(.9);
   filter: blur(4px) saturate(.7) brightness(.9);
}
```

and if you want it to look extra snazzy, you can add an animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blur-animation {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px) ;
    -moz-filter: blur(0px);
    -o-filter: blur(0px);
    -ms-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);

  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px) saturate(.5) brightness(.8);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px) saturate(.7) brightness(.9);
    -o-filter: blur(5px) saturate(.7) brightness(.9);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px)saturate(.7) brightness(.9);
    filter: blur(5px) saturate(.7) brightness(.9);

  }
}

html.background-blur-animation .backgrounds {
   -webkit-animation-name: blur-animation;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this line in your source

```
 html.blur.backgrounds {     
                   //no (. sign)is required in front of .html or copy the above line and paste it.
```

Comment: Try it,please reply me if it failed

Comment: hi vijay, thanks for posting the answer -- the problem was that I had a "." in front of "html"... so yes, this works, thanks!